# Use HTML pages into GWT application

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, cordova

I want to use html pages into phone-gap application with the help of GWT application.

I have one HTML page with css and javascript file. So How can I integrate with GWT web application.?

So By the end of compiling, I can use into phone-gap project for same as I designed the page.

can anyone tell me steps for this procedure.?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Vic: Still not using iFrame. Can you tell me in brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *iframe*. It is a standard HTML tag (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), where you can put a link to another page and the page will be embedded in your document.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

You can add it programmatically as well.

```
public class FrameExample implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
        Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");

        // Add it to the root panel.
        RootPanel.get().add(frame);
    }

}
```

The example is from http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it but this may help.
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/

Heard it is pretty good